# Decorate a @Html.Textbox with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm trying to decorate some @Html.Textboxes  and a button in a contactform with bootstrap, but I still wan´t to use the functionality in  razor.
But it dosent seem to work to give a normal text razor functionality like `@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message, new { rows = "4", cols = "40" })`
If i put a type, class or id it stops working. Can I wrap it in a class maybe? Or is there any common way/standard to design a asp.net mvc4 with twitter bootstrap?

Comment: are you saying that when you do new { id = ?, class = ?} the razor syntax breaks? if that's the case make sure you escape id and class, they're special, so that your attributes look like this [new { \@id = ?, \@class = ?}] minus the \ character

Comment: Actually I normally more complaining that the bootstrap template dosen´t work as normal in prior for the functionality. But I will check in Abbas Amiris answer. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, using bootstrap in MVC makes views complicated and sometimes out of control, so I recommend you using "TwitterBootstrapMvc" at https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/TwitterBootstrapMvc. It makes your code and markup clean and easy to debug and change. It is well designed and almost cover all aspects of bootstrap.

"TwitterBootstrapMvc" at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc would be helpful to learn how to use it.

Comment: That's right, a better documentation/tutorial has been provided at https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation/V2